# Building WPF control in Windows Form: Error message saying "make sure the type has a default constructor"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wpf-controls, windows-forms-designer, windowsformsintegration

I am creating a custom WPF control in windows form for a temperature dial in vb.net. When I try to add the WPF control in windows form using **ElementHost**, I Get the ***error message "Make sure the type has a default constructor".*** And yes I have added `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll` to my project's references.

VB Code for Custom Control

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Data
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging
Imports System.Windows.Navigation
Imports System.Windows.Shapes
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Integration

Namespace CSV_FILE

    Public Class Temperature_Dial
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
        Public pointervalue As Double
        Private arrowPointer As System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
        Public Sub Temperature_Dial()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Public Sub InitializeComponent()
            ' Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub changevalue()
            Dim rotate As RotateTransform = New RotateTransform(pointervalue)
            arrowPointer.RenderTransform = rotate

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

XML Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Temperature_Dial"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSV_FILE"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="368.545" Height="463.273">
    
        <Grid x:Name="Dial" Margin="-13,-66,0,-50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="379">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Temp_gauge_without_needles.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        
            <Rectangle x:Name="Value" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="90,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="dial_values.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
            
        <Rectangle x:Name="arrowPointer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="87,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" RenderTransformOrigin="0.77,0.48">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="2612.226"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-3.86853" Y="-0.314352"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="NEEDLE.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

    </Grid>
  
</UserControl>
```

Please help me to resolve the error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide MCVE code inline in the question.  Without seeing the code, I might guess that there is an issue with a custom constructor added (`Sub New` with arguments), whereas WPF wants you to have a default constructor (`Sub New` with no arguments).

Comment: @Craig. Please do my check query, I have updated it. Thank you

Comment: You still don't have a default constructor.  `Sub Temperature_Dial` is not a constructor, it's a callable routine named "Temperature_Dial".  In VB, the syntax for a constructor is `Sub New`.  You might be confused by the syntax for a ctor in C# where the ctor has the same name as the entity being constructed.